# Pay with Paypal Button Stopped Working (PHP)

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have been using PHP PayPal NVP codes to pay for products via a web portal.
The portal has two options 'direct payment' and 'pay with PayPal'. But recently without any code change Pay with Paypal (Yellow Buttion) has stopped working in which it now redirects to a 404 page having the url as "undefined". Here is the 'Pay with PayPal' button form code.

```
<form method="post" action="../includes/paypal/ReviewOrder.php">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif" 
value="Pay with PayPal" 
style='background:url(https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif); width:150px; height:33px;' />

</form>
```

The direct payment method still works fine while this method stopped working with a 404 redirection to http://my-site-name.com/undefined
Please help me solve this issue. This PHP nvp bundle was a bit older but why did it stopped working recently?

Comment: This snippet doesn't give us much to help you with.  Need to see the raw API request and response that is getting sent to and from PayPal.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I removed the form and put the "../includes/paypal/ReviewOrder.php" to a normal anchor tag and it worked nicely with redirecting to PayPal.